# Virtual Machine cannot get DHCP when host connects via WiFi

Tags: dhcp

We recently upgraded our networking hardware (L2+ switches and routers) to bring the office up to IPv6 connectivity. Since then, we have had a strange problem.

We are mainly an Apple Macintosh office but we have some need to run Windows software so we use VMware Fusion to run Windows in Virtual Machines (VMs). People who are using wired connections to the network are doing fine, and people using laptops connected via WiFi have no trouble with their OS X networking, but their Windows VMs cannot get addresses via DHCP. When the Windows VMs are manually assigned static IP addresses, they work fine.

I have verified that DHCP request packets come from the laptops on WiFi but they only reach the DHCP server when they come from OS X, not from Windows.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a separate network interface, the VM creates a new MAC address, different from the one on the host computer. On wired Ethernet, the VM is able to use its generated MAC address on the L2 network because it can see all the traffic on the wire. On WiFi, because of wireless security protocols, it cannot use its L2 MAC address and has to use a specialized bridge.

This means that when the DHCP request hits the wired network, the source MAC address is the VM's generated MAC address when it comes from a wired computer, but it is the host's MAC address when it comes from a computer connected via WiFi.

This means that DHCP requests coming from VM's on WiFi-connected laptops fail the MAC Address Verification test provided by DHCP Snooping: the L2 source MAC address does not match the L3 requester MAC address.

Our solution was to turn off DHCP Snooping MAC Address Verification for the office WiFi, though we plan on leaving it on for the guest WiFi and telling guests to use NAT rather than Bridged connections in their VMs should the need arise.

Comment: Wow, I thought the wireless access point was blocking broadcast messages. But after capturing the dhcp packets, I agree with and verify your explanation. I don't think this question is off topic at all!